# Slider value, int to binary conversion

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'd like to change the value property of a UISlider value to its binary form.

As for what I've done:

```
-(IBAction)setValue:(id)sender
{

    int value =(int)([sliderValue value] *200);


    NSLog(@"slider value int %i", value);

    NSLog(@"hex 0x%02X",(unsigned int)value);

    NSMutableArray *xx;
    [xx addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value]];

    NSLog(@"%@",xx);

    NSInteger theNumber = [[xx objectAtIndex:value]intValue];
    NSLog(@"%@",theNumber);
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString string];
    NSInteger numberCopy = theNumber; // so won't change original value
    for(NSInteger i = 0; i < 8 ; i++) {
        // Prepend "0" or "1", depending on the bit
        [str insertString:((numberCopy & 1) ? @"1" : @"0") atIndex:0];
        numberCopy >>= 1;
    }

    NSLog(@"Binary version: %@", str);

}
```

However, there's a problem. Whenever the slider value change it's converted into an integer and hexadecimal, but not into binary. Can anyone help me find where I've made a mistake?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not converted to binary"? What kind of output do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: When i increase or decrease the slider (value) changes, as i want that value to change every time to binary.. if you check my program i changed the slider value from float to int , like that i want to be convert to binary

Comment: Oh, I should just have read the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)setValue:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger value = (NSInteger)([sliderValue value] * 200.0);

    NSMutableString *binaryString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    for(NSInteger numberCopy = value; numberCopy > 0; numberCopy >>= 1)
    {
        // Prepend "0" or "1", depending on the bit
        [binaryString insertString:((numberCopy & 1) ? @"1" : @"0") atIndex:0];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", binaryString);
}
```

This should log the binary representation of the value. Beyond the lack of an initializer for your array (which I've cut out completely for brevity) your original was flawed in that you used an indice that went from 0 to 8, meaning it would only log the first 8 bits of the value. `NSInteger` is either 32 or 64 bits, which is why the original code you pulled from Stack Overflow instead checked to see if the value we were bit-shifting had reached zero yet. Also, the correct specifier for `NSInteger` is `%ld` after casting the `NSInteger` to a `long`, not `%@`. `%@` logs the string returned by an object's `description` method.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
NSMutableArray *xx;
[xx addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:value]];
```

You don't create an instance of NSMutableArray, you just declare a pointer to it. Alloc-init it and it'll be fine.

Comment: Actually, although the OP obviously copy and pasted Adam Rosenfield's binary conversion snippet, they messed a few things up. For one thing, an `NSInteger` isn't 8 bits, hence why the original version didn't use an indice but checked to make sure the bit-shifted value was still above zero. Also, they are trying to log the value of a `NSInteger` as they would a `NSNumber` when they should probably be using `%d`.